# PHP - Find number between 2 Unicode characters

Tags: php, regex, unicode, preg-match

Simple problem but i sux at regular expressions so i need here ur help.

What do i need to type to find a number between two first signs: •

Find out its codes but it doenst help me much: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm

Do you know what should i type in for example preg_match function to make it work?

Example:
• 12345 • TESTTESTTEST

Example Output:
12345

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's your expected output if the input is `• 12345 • TESTTESTTEST  • 12345 • TESTTESTTEST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match a specific Unicode code point, use \x{FFFF} where FFFF is the hexadecimal number of the code point you want to match. You can omit leading zeros in the hexadecimal number between the curly braces. Since \x by itself is not a valid regex token, \x{1234} can never be confused to match \x 1234 times. It always matches the Unicode code point U+1234. \x{1234}{5678} will try to match code point U+1234 exactly 5678 times.

Anyway, what you're probably looking for is something like this:

```
\x{2022} (\d*) \x{2022}
```

As for the (\d*) part, it basically means match any digit infinite times, and assign this bit of the pattern as a match (braces stand for capture groups)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found out a way to do it a bit easier.
I used preg_match() with $pattern = "/[0-9]{1,}/";

Huh xD